# Webpack can't resolve @import of scss/css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

I have a main Stylesheet `style.scss`, which I imported in my main JavaScript file `script.js`:

```js
import "./style.scss";
```

This works great, and I could build my website that way in dev mode. *Now* I wanted to try and use separate Stylesheet and import them in my main stylesheet with the `@import` rule, like so:

```
@import "./blocks/SCSS/test.scss" screen and (min-width: 600px);
```

But now I get this error message:

```
ERROR in ./dev/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./dev/style.scss)  
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):  
Error: Can't resolve './blocks/SCSS/test.scss' in 'D:\Art Files\Design\Eigene Projekte\WP Book Theme Dev\dev'
```

And I don't understand why it can't resolve it. I use modules for my JavaScript as well, which works great. But now with SCSS, it does not work at all.

I tried googling for a solution and checked out several open threads, none could help me.
Here are some I checked out on Stackoverflow:

- [Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690819/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-postcss-loader-src-index-js)
- [Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): CssSyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952866/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-css-loader-dist-cjs-js-csssyntaxerror)
- [Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522396/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-sass-loader-dist-cjs-js)
- [Webpack: getting this error: build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830978/webpack-getting-this-error-build-failed-from-node-modules-css-loader-dist-c)

My Node version was `12.18.3`, where I had the error first. Now I updated my node to the LTS to `14.15.4`, still the same error.

Here are my Webpack config files:

```js
// webpack.common.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./dev/script.js",
  
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/images",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};


// webpack.dev.js

const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./dev/post.html",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "script.dev.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "./",
  },
});
```

Here are my webpack dependencies:

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to fix my problem. Amaresh already mentioned something, about what I might be missing, but that didn't help me out with my problem, as I was given no real explanation on why that would help.
In the end, I did install [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)*, and since `node-sass` is deprecated, I didn't pay any mind to it.

The way I used `@import` was probably wrong. I was trying to do it the native CSS way ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/@import)), but SCSS might have been overwriting that. `@import` by SCSS is also deprecated by now and not recommended. When I rechecked the SCSS Website, I went to their guide on how to use SCSS, and they mentioned how I could use `@use` to import another stylesheet. What I learned was that I need to use [Partials](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4). I had to lead filenames with an underscore to create a namespace for that, and import it using the `@use` rule.

From their example:

```
// _base.scss
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

```
// styles.scss
@use 'base';

.inverse {
  background-color: base.$primary-color;
  color: white;
}
```

** I don't know if the installation of `sass` actually helped or not. Since the package is dealing with JavaScript, which I have not done so in my file. But since the package is also mentioned in the [`sass-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader), I will keep it.*

What is important to remember when using `@use` is how you handle the file in the new file.

```
// src/_list.scss
@mixin list{
    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        li {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

By only calling the URL, you have to specify the namespace and then what you want to use from that namespace.

```
// styles.scss
@use "src/list";

header {
  @include list.list;
}
```

You can call a new namespace and give it a custom name.

```
// styles.scss
@use "src/list" as myList;

header {
  @include myList.list;
}
```

Or you can call it and name it with an asterisk, making it available, without having to write the namespace when calling it.

```
// styles.scss
@use "src/list" as *;

header {
  @include list;
}
```

For further reading, [please check out their documentation on `@use`.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have installed all these packages:

1. sass (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)
2. sass-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader)
3. css-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader)
4. style-loader(https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader)
5. node-sass (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

you might be missing **node-sass**

Comment: Why would I need ``node-sass`` or ``sass`` if I am not calling it from a JavaScrip file? I don't see how I would need an API for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632291/sass-loader-and-webpack-4 @Mähnenwolf

Comment: Right, but that is not my problem. Before I was trying to import another file into my stylesheet, I got my *.css file back. Everything works, the only problem starts, when I try to import a second scss file into my main scss file.

Comment: @import "./blocks/SCSS/test" while import inside your css files don't .scss extension
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import